# How do I hide "Save and Add Another" button from edit form in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I applied a rails_admin gem in my Rails app. I want to remove some unnecessary buttons in a specific model edit form, and add my own custom button instead. Please see the screenshot for what I'd like to remove.

[image: Snapshot of layout]

Comment: did you resolve? how?

Comment: @montells Yes I resolve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@montells Copy https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/_submit_buttons.html.haml this page in your repo at "views/rails_admin/main/_submit_buttons.html.haml"

Now in this file, you can put the condition in which page you want to remove button
e.g.

```
- if params[:model_name]
 - if params[:model_name] != "model_name_in_which_you_want_hide_button"
   "Paste above url view"
```

Comment: Hey @ashvin, how did you configured this button templates? Could you help me out here?

Comment: Hi @Agustin, which buttons you are talking about?

Comment: The `save and edit` ones, in fact my question was a bit wrong, I wanted to know where or how did you configure rails_admin to use `views/rails_admin/main/_submit_button.html.haml`, thanks in advance! @ashvin

Comment: Please read my answer it will solve your problem. Still if you didn't get let me know.

Comment: I did that but I am missing some config, is it possible that you send me the config file example? The exact part on where the buttons are configured on rails_admin.rb. Thanks @ashvin

Comment: Rails Admin is 'magic' in that there doesn't need to be an config. If you have a view/rails_admin/main file with the same name was one that's default it just uses yours rather than the default.